# A Button automatically add a new Button with a Name

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm really new to Xamarin.forms so pls be patient with me.

I try to give the user the chance to click on a button to create a new Button and initially the Button Name at the same time.

The user can create as many buttons as he wants, showed in a ScrollView.
After he presses the button I want a little popup where he can enter the Name of the button.

```
void Mainpage_button_addNewButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entry = new Namenseingabe();
    Button button = new Button
    {
        //Text = entry.Name,    Here i try to get the Value from the Entry            
        AutomationId = id.ToString(),                
    };
    MainPageButtonStackLayout.Children.Add(button);
    mainPageButtons.Add(button);
}
```

Here is the xaml from the Entry:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Entry x:Name="EntryValue" Margin="20,20,20,10" Placeholder="Name" Completed="EntryValue_Completed"></Entry>                
            <Button Margin="20,0,20,0" Text="Save"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

I only get the value in the Method `EntryValue_Completed()` like here:

```
private void EntryValue_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var a = ((Entry)sender).Text;
}
```

But how I can get the value in the method where I need it? Maybe you can help me with how I can do it better or faster.

Comment: are both EntryValue_Completed and Mainpage_button_addNewButton_Clicked in the same class? If so you create a property in the class that is scoped to the whole class

Comment: No.
EntryValue_Completed is in public partial class Namenseingabe : ContentView
and
Mainpage_button_addNewButton_Clicked is in public partial class MainPage : ContentPage

Comment: You need an Event aggregator implementation basically then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you want to have one popup window to enter Button name and save this Button, I suggest you can use Rg.Plugins.Popup to do this.

Firstly, install **Rg.Plugins.Popup** by Nuget packages, then create popup page like the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<popup:PopupPage
x:Class="demo2.simplecontrol.Page8"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Frame Margin="15" BackgroundColor="White">
        <StackLayout
            Padding="10,5"
            IsClippedToBounds="True"
            Spacing="3">
            <Entry x:Name="entry1" />
            <Button
                x:Name="btn1"
                Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
                Text="save" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ScrollView>

</popup:PopupPage>

public partial class Page8:PopupPage
{  
    public Page8 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();        
    }



    private async void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<Page7, string>(new Page7(), "add", entry1.Text);
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
    }      
}
```

Then using **MessagingCenter** to send the entry value.

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo2.simplecontrol.Page7"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout1">
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="create button" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


public partial class Page7 : ContentPage
{     
    public Page7 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page7, string>(this, "add", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            Button btn = new Button()
            {
                Text = (string)arg

            };
            stacklayout1.Children.Add(btn);
        });

    }


    private async void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Page8());
    }
}
```

About using Rg.Plugins.Popup, you can take a look:https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/blob/master/src/Demo/Demo/Pages/LoginPopupPage.xaml.cs

about using MessagingCenter, you can refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

If my reply solved your issue, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works.
And Rg.Plugins.Popup is a nice plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Event Aggregator pattern. An easy library to this with for newcomers is MVVMLight Library [Messenger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx)

With the concept being one class will notify the other of the entry name and pass the entered string

I also noticed you are using Xamarin.Forms so a quick google shows they have their own messenger service to accomplish what you want: [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

You will use the messaging center and publish the entry name, the main page will have already subscribed to pick up any publishes

Comment: Thank you.

I will read through the guide after I am at home.